# Tuple + Lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda

My understanding is that key can accept functions as a parameter to sort, if I'm using [] to access the tuple. Why do I still get "Type Error: 'Tuple' object is not callable."?

```
list_ = [(34, 21, 56), (24, 12, 32), (42, 34, 42), (27, 11, 32)]
m = sorted(list_, key=(lambda x: x[1], list_))
print(m)
```

Expected output:
Sorted list based on second element of each tuple in the list.

```
[(27, 11, 32), (24, 12, 32), (34, 21, 56), (42, 34, 42)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up the `sorted` line. The entire section `(lambda x:x[1], list_)` is passed to the `key` parameter.

`(lambda x:x[1], list_)` is a tuple, and not callable.

Replace the line with this:

```
m = sorted(list_, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

and it should work.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much for the clarity, chw21!